# using fp_identify_finger from libfprint giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, fingerprint

I'm trying to use this function on my code to perform a search among all my others saved prints in order to know if an employee did check his entrance or exit, but still getting the segmentation fault every time I call this function and the program closes, it ask me to put my finger and once it finished scanning it crashes. I'm doing all this in a gtk+-2.0 C++ program.

And this is the page of the API I'm trying to use https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-stable/

I've already tried calling this function from C

this is the part of the code where I try to identify the finger print of the edlg_enroll_data after runing an enroll process and the device in fpdev already enabled

this is how I declared my variables

```
struct fp_dev *fpdev = NULL;
static struct fp_print_data *edlg_enroll_data = NULL;
```

this is how I initialized the device

```
static gboolean enable_device()
{
    struct fp_dscv_dev **discovered_devs;
    discovered_devs = fp_discover_devs();

    if (!discovered_devs)
        return FALSE;

    g_assert(discovered_devs);

    if (discovered_devs[0]){
         fpdev = fp_dev_open(discovered_devs[0]);
         fp_dscv_devs_free(discovered_devs);
         return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

and this is how I initialize the edlg_enroll_data

```
static void edlg_run_enroll_stage()
{
    int r;
    int passed = 0;
    struct fp_img *img = NULL;
    gchar *tmp;

    while (gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();

    r = fp_enroll_finger_img(fpdev, &edlg_enroll_data, &img);
    if (r < 0) {
        return;
    }
```

the same device and the same fp_print_data are working correctly in other functions

```
struct fp_print_data **gallery;
gallery = (fp_print_data**)malloc(sizeof(*gallery) * (2));
gallery[0]=edlg_enroll_data;
gallery[1]=NULL;
size_t *size = 0;
return fp_identify_finger(fpdev, gallery, size);
and can't get past that identify function
```

I expected the function to return an Int (1 for example) and saving the position of the finger print that matched in the gallery I provided. The only thing I think it could be is the way I initialize the gallery.

Comment: Do you not need `fp_dscv_dev_get_driver (struct fp_dscv_dev *dev);` or `fp_dscv_dev_get_devtype (struct fp_dscv_dev *dev);`? Have you looked at `fp_dev_get_nr_enroll_stages (struct fp_dev *dev);` to determine the number of times you must enroll the device to complete a scan? The [Devices operations](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-stable/libfprint-Devices-operations.html) is fairly clear that may require enrolling more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Your is either related `fpdev` and `edlg_enroll_data` remain `NULL` pointers unless they are initialized in code you have not shown. Presuming they are initialized, your `fp_identify_finger` function has a declaration of:

> ```
> int
> fp_identify_finger (struct fp_dev *dev,
>                     struct fp_print_data **print_gallery,
>                     size_t *match_offset);
> ```

The parameters are defined as:

> ```
> dev             the device to perform the scan.
>
> print_gallery   NULL-terminated array of pointers to the prints to 
>                 identify against. Each one must have been previously 
>                 enrolled with a device compatible to the device 
>                 selected to perform the scan.
>
> match_offset    output location to store the array index of the matched 
>                 gallery print (if any was found). Only valid if 
>                 FP_VERIFY_MATCH was returned.
> ```

If either `dev` (your `fp_dev`) or `print_gallery[0]` (your `gallery[0]`) are not properly initialized *and* validated, that could very easily lead to a SegFault.

Further, Gtk+2 is a C API, meant to be compiled with a C compiler, not C++. You are further encouraged to use [`g_malloc ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-malloc) or [`g_slice_new()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Slices.html#g-slice-new) when allocating within Gtk+ programs, as checking the return of the allocation is unnecessary as the program terminates on an allocation failure.

In your case you never even check whether the call to `malloc` succeeds before making use of the storage (that may not have been allocated at all -- in that case a SegFault is likely as well) There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is the best ideas I can provide on where the likely source of your SegFault resides. If you are failing to validate the initializations for `fpdev` and `edlg_enroll_data`, the same way you failed to validate whether the allocation of the pointers for `gallery` succeeded, it is very likely you have a failure in one of those areas.

Comment: I provided more info about the initialization of the finger print and the device

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it, I was missing an & when passing the parameter to store the position of the found finger print like this:

`return fp_identify_finger(fpdev, gallery, &size);`

and that solved it.